# QGIS - Aligning Cells from Multiple Overlay DEM's

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, dem, overlay, alignment

I am modelling a volcano with a changing landform using 5 overlaying DEMs at different stages of the volcano collapse. I need the cells of each DEMs to line up vertically so I can obtain elevation differences between the 5 sperate stages.

I have 5 raster DEM's covering the approx. the same terrain, all on the same projection and all approx at 50 metre cell resolution. I try using Clip by Raster Extent to bring each DEM to the same spatial extent plus Warp to change all cells in each DEM to 50 metres. My results always show slight variations in the final extent and cell size. Is there another way around this.

I also have ArcGIS Pro available if it better achieved in this application.